# Prevent FutureBuilder recalling future function every build

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

How to prevent FutureBuilder future function to be recalled on every build? In below case, the category.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<List<Category>> categories =
      CategoryRepository().getCategories();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: categories,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Category>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return SomeWidget()
            } else {
              return OtherWidget();
            }
          }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

In the documentation, to prevent that, the *future* should be obtained before, i.e. *initState()*. I have tried to move the assignment of the *categories* to the *initState()* function. But the function still called when state change / rebuild.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late Future<List<Category>> categories;

  @override
  void initState() {
    categories = CategoryRepository().getCategories();
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Comment: wdym by _But the function still called when state change / rebuild_?
Which state? which function?

Comment: Also, always call `super.initState` first

Comment: you are not calling it on every build, but every time the _HomeScreenState is created

Comment: @vincendep So how/where should I put the categories initialization/method call?

Comment: you are already doing it well. if you don't want to create the future every time the home screen is pushed with the navigator just create the future above the navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way -

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<List<Category>> categories;

  @override
  void initState() {
   if(categories==null) categories = CategoryRepository().getCategories();
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it says "LateInitializationError: Field categories should be initialized". Why should you check if the categories is null?

Comment: remove late from  Future<List<Category>> categories

Comment: If categories is null then it will initialise categories by calling categories = CategoryRepository().getCategories() else it will not and your future will not recall

Comment: It produce another error: "Field 'categories' should be initialized because its type 'Future<List<Category>>'" doesn't allow null.

Comment: make categories nullable by putting ? like this   `Future<List<Category>>? categories`

Comment: It remove the error, but the future is still recalled.

Comment: Still recall means on setState it is re- building or getCategories method are calling again?

Comment: Yes, the method still called